# Get (x, y) coords of the JFrame's minimize button no matter the screen size?

Tags: java, jframe, coordinates, screen-resolution

I'm trying to figure out how to always be able to find the x and y coordinates of the JFrame's minimize button no matter the display's size. Looked it up on S/O and other sites and could not find anything.

Comment: You can't do this from within Java itself (assuming you're using a native look and feel) and would have to resort to using a JNI/JNA based solution

Comment: Ok, is it possible to always get the coordinates of the JFrame itself, and then based on its size, add/subtract x and y coords of the mouse until you get to the point of preference on the JFrame using the Robot.

Comment: `getLocation` will give you the x/y position of the window, `getSize` will get you the size

Comment: There isn't any solution available in java. You can create your custom window to achieve this or you might have to look into some native solution.